# How is it possible to increment a variable based on radio button selection in angular

Tags: angular

I have two radio-groups as shown below

```
                        <mat-radio-group
                          [(ngModel)]="firstGroup">
                          <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" value=1>Thin Build</mat-radio-button>
                          <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" value=2>Medium Build</mat-radio-button>
                          <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" value=3>Large, solid body build</mat-radio-button>
                        </mat-radio-group>



                        <mat-radio-group
                          [(ngModel)]="secondGroup">
                          <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" value=1>Tall by nature</mat-radio-button>
                          <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" value=2>Medium Strength</mat-radio-button>
                          <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" value=3>Calm, Slow and relaxed</mat-radio-button>

                        </mat-radio-group>
```

I have the ngIf statement and its working, but the variable is not incrementing

```
                        <div *ngIf="firstGroup == 1">Value is  {{bvariable + 1}}</div>
                        <div *ngIf="secondGroup == 1">Value is {{bvariable + 1}}</div>
```

bvariable is initialised in the TS

```
    export class MainNavComponent { bvariable =0;}
```

If the user clicks both the radio button with value 1, the bvariable need to be 2, but its showing as 1

not sure, i'm in the correct way.
please correct me,if i'm wrong.

Comment: {{bvariable + 1}} this is showing data not functionality. so its value 0 then show to you 1

Comment: use change function to increase bvariable and show just it in html

Answer (score 1):

it is not clear what should happens in other combination of options, but you can use `ngModelChange` to update `bvariable` based on both group selection as follow

```js
    <mat-radio-group
      [(ngModel)]="firstGroup"
      (ngModelChange)="onFirstGroupChange()">

      <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" [value]="1">Thin Build</mat-radio-button>
      <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" [value]="2">Medium Build</mat-radio-button>
      <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" [value]="3">Large, solid body build</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
    <mat-radio-group
      [(ngModel)]="secondGroup"
      (ngModelChange)="onSecondGroupChange()">

      <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" [value]="1">Tall by nature</mat-radio-button>
      <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" [value]="2">Medium Strength</mat-radio-button>
      <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" [value]="3">Calm, Slow and relaxed</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>

    export class MainNavComponent {

      bvariable = 0;
      firstGroup = 0;
      secondGroup = 0;

      onFirstGroupChange() {
        if(this.firstGroup === 1 && this.secondGroup === 1) {
          this.bvariable = this.firstGroup + this.secondGroup;
        } else {
          this.bvariable = 0;
        }
      }
      onSecondGroupChange() {
        if(this.firstGroup === 1 && this.secondGroup === 1) {
          this.bvariable = this.firstGroup + this.secondGroup;
        } else {
          this.bvariable = 0;
        }
      }
    }
```

you can use same handler for both radio groups, also if you need select value as number you need to use value binding as follow `[value]="1"`

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-radio-group-onchange?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: wrong logic. U increase for every change. U should countrol if first group checked and second group checked with wanted value

Comment: @radhik : i tried your first code, it worked, but recording for all options.. but its same as andrias answer. I have a total of 10 radio groups which have 3 options each. bvariable is for option1, bvariable2 for option2 and bvariable3 for option3.  If i get count for each, i can analyse which option the user selected the most. But your code workedm but its recording the duplicate entries as well. we may need to set a flag to stop that...Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

The value of `bvariable` never changes here, as you've initialized it with the value 0 and then it gets never reassigned. So in your html you're just counting +1 onto your variable for the output but this does NOT change the value of your variable. For the compiler it just means: 'give out: 0+1' and as 0+1 is a mathemitical operation it gets calculated before printing.

If you really want to change the value of your variable do it in a function in your ts-file and call this function in your html on-click, just like this:

```
<mat-radio-group
    [(ngModel)]="firstGroup">
    <mat-radio-button (click)="add(1)" class="example-radio-button" value=1>Thin Build</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button (click)="add(2)" class="example-radio-button" value=2>Medium Build</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button (click)="add(3)" class="example-radio-button" value=3>Large, solid body build</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

And in the function in your .ts-file:

```
add(numberToAdd: number): void {
   this.bvariable += numberToAdd;
}
```

Comment: the function add(numberToAdd) adds the given number to your bvariable. So if you call it with the value of the button it should work.

Comment: Yes thanks, it worked,  is there any way to place a flag to stop duplicate entries. Eg. if we change to option2 and back to option1, again its counting.

Comment: [(ngModel)]="built" [hidden]=check  use this flag function to hide that radio group to avoid duplicate entries.. thanks guys..

Answer (score 1):

put change event to drowdowns

```
 (change)="GroupChange()"
```

in component

```
GroupChange(){
      this.bvariable =0;
      if(this.firstGroup ==1){this.bvariable++}
      if(this.secondGroup ==1){this.bvariable++}
    }
```

in html just show it

```
<div >Value is  {{bvariable}}</div>
```